# How to return a plist using the restlet api

Tags: objective-c, rest, plist, restlet

does anyone know how to return a plist / property list using restlets REST api?  I'm connecting to my iPhone app and objective-c works much nicer with plists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you intend to generate the PLists? Using a template engine or a specialized library such as [JPList](http://jplist.sourceforge.net/)?

Restlet representations can then wrap the result and send it back to your iPhone app.